# push notification con PHP..se me reemplazan las notificación y no quiero,

Tags: php, android, firebase

busque en el foro pero no encontré respuesta...
Resulta que mando notificaciones a mi disposito desde PHP y llegan sin problema, pero el DETALLE es que cuando envió otra notificación, esta reemplaza a la otra, es decir... no se muestra una sobre otra, curiosamente si la notificacion la envio desde firebase, si que me las muestra correctamente, si mando 5 notificacion, yo miro mi telefono y tengo las 5..una arriba de otra, en cambio desde PHP si mando 5 notificaciones solo me muestra la ULTIMA. La pregunta es... me faltara alguna configuracion?? algo asi como un collapse no se algo? (lo de collapse me lo invente xD)de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Pero estas usando el api de firebase para enviarla? Porque si no cambias un parámetro (que no recuerdo si se llama topic o tag o algo) se manda el default y es a propósito que se pise. Cuando usas la consola de firebase nunca es la misma "campaña" sino que se regenera ese parametro

Comment: no, estaba mandandola desde PHP, pero lo pude solucionar asi que publique la respuesta por si anda otro programador golpeandose la cabeza con el teclado haha... ojala les sirva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando encontre que habia que cambiarle el ID a la notificacion, intente hacer el clasico ID++ pero no funciono, asi que hice lo siguiente...cree un nro random y ese valor se lo pase al manager.notify

```
Random ran=new Random();
int nu=ran.nextInt(1000)+1;
```

genere un numero random, curiosamente creando un int por si solo y agregandole el ++ no funcionaba, y para terminar se pasa la variable "nu" al notify.

```
manager.notify(nu,builder.build());
```

a mi me funciono, ojala le sirva alguien

Comment: No olvides cuando te sea posible marqués tu respuesta como aceptada

Comment: un numero random de 1 al 1000 no es muy random, se empezaran a repetir los numeros en muy poco tiempo

Comment: No es el método más elegante pero inventaste una solución y eso define a un desarrollador talentoso. Chapeau, colega.

Comment: si, no es muy elegante..pero creado un int nro=1; y luego poner....manager.notify(nro++,builder.build()); no me funciono =(